# JavaFX show and hide a node

Tags: java, javafx

This is based on [Oracle Layout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG), where there is `HBox` with two buttons.

I added two more Nodes (nodeCurrent and nodeProjected) but I cannot implement logic to show/hide nodeCurrent/nodeProjected from the main Layout. For example:

```
buttonCurrent.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            nodeProjected.setVisible(false);
            nodeCurrent.setVisible(true);
        }
```

I also tried with `setManaged. However, whatever I try it does not work correctly. So, what's the proper way to implement show/hide toggle for a node in JavaFX? Or is there a smarted way to show/hide panes in JavaFX?

**Update**

To clarify a bit. These are defined as public:

```
public GridPane root;
public GridPane dataform;
public GridPane search;
```

And added to root:

```
dataform = addDataForm();
root.add(dataform, 0, 1);
search = addSearchForm();
search.setVisible(false);
root.add(search, 0, 1)
```

There are two buttons that should toggle visibility:

```
btnSearch.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                dataform.setVisible(false);
                search.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println("Search!");
            }
        });
```

But after clicking on them, I get:

[image]

Comment: "Does not work correctly". So what does it actually do?

Comment: How do you add these nodeProjected & nodeCurrent to the scene?

Comment: If the node should be invisible and ignored for the purpose of layouting the `HBox` children you need to set both the `visible` and the `managed` properties to `false`. However you never properly describe the expected behavior...

Comment: @James_D I can only hide one node, but the other does not show. I also tried managed properties and combined with visible, but cannot make it work.

Comment: @purringpigeon I define them as public variables ant the beginning of the class and then instantiate in start() with methods that return nodes (as clarified above).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted. Create a [MCVE] and post it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself, because I recreated the GUI in FXML and replicated the issue. The solution is adding GridPanes in another, parent, GridPane - and then to the root:

```
- root
-- GridPane
--- GridPaneDataForm
--- GridPaneSearchForm
```